# Remove product from mini cart message Magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

Where can I find the following message that appears when you remove an item from the mini cart?

"Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's located in magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js:

Line 71

```
'confirmMessage': $.mage.__(
    'Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?'
)
```

Comment: how can i add a product name along with this message which i gonna remove ?

Comment: Hi @Shaz Can you please let me know how an alert box getting while  deleting item

Comment: 'button': {
               
                'remove': '#mini-cart a.action.delete',
          
            },

Comment: When i comment the Line:52 the alert gone out, but where he specify the alert, i dont know how knockout js is worked.

Comment: Why dont you just create a new question? this is not a forum.

Comment: Yes, @Shaz  sorry for the comment:

Comment: Please  find the  question:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192306/magento2-mini-cart-item-delete-alert

Comment: And how can you translate it without getting it overwritten by an update?