# Magento2 mini cart item delete alert

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, delete, alert

Can anyone let me know, How an alert box getting delete an item popup, from minicart:
location below:

line 71:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js
```

Where defined the alert for this, Please let me know the location of alert. in magento2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I you are still looking for an answer, the modal confirmation is created in 
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js` and it's a parameter named `confirm`:

```
        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            confirm({
                content: self.options.confirmMessage,
                actions: {
                    /** @inheritdoc */
                    confirm: function () {
                        self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
                    },

                    /** @inheritdoc */
                    always: function (e) {
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: In template/minicart/item/default.html  this code create delete button

 <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>

in this code where is define to call click event in sidebar.js