# how to disable minicart remove product confirmation popup?

Tags: magento2, porto-theme

i want to remove minicart product remove confirmation popup in magento 2.3 theme porto smartwave

https://prnt.sc/u3kh1f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this link to create a new theme: [Create a new storefront theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html#theme-gen-walkthrough)

If frontend theme is already exists then copy your core file into theme folder.

From:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js

To:

> app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/Magento_Checkout/web/js/sidebar.js

And replace the following code:

From:

```
/**
 * @param {jQuery.Event} event
 */
events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    confirm({
        content: self.options.confirmMessage,
        actions: {
            /** @inheritdoc */
            confirm: function () {
                self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            always: function (e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

To:

```
/**
 * @param {jQuery.Event} event
 */
events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your try using js.you want to change magento 2 default js check this link :-

**[Magento2 mini cart item delete alert](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192306/magento2-mini-cart-item-delete-alert)**

And Second you want to add custom js form.phtml file check this link:-

**[Confirmation popup before removing item from cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231129/confirmation-popup-before-removing-item-from-cart)**

**`THANKS.`**